# Get Image as a response from HttpWebRequest in HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, httpwebresponse

I am using HttpHandler in my Asp.Net MVC project. I have another MVC API project that return image as a response. Using HttpWebRequest I am able to call the API, there is no error in code but I can't view the Image in the page.

My Code:

HttpHandler code:

```
var currentResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;

string URL = "http://localhost:50417/API/GetThumbnail";
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
                    request.KeepAlive = false;
                    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    request.Timeout = 30000;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    StreamReader streamr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


                    currentResponse.Write(streamr.ReadToEnd());
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.Add(new Route("Thumbnail/getImage", new ThumbnailImageRouteHandler()));
```

index.csHtml

```
<img src="/Thumbnail/getImage" />
```

Comment: Did you try specifying the contenttype? Can you download/view the image if you open the URL in a browser?

Comment: @Fixation yes I can download the image if I open URL in browser, also I tried contenttype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you set the `ContentType` properly and simply copy the response stream to the output, like this:

```
response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(currentResponse.OutputStream);
currentResponse.ContentType = response.ContentType;
```

Comment: It worked for me when I replaced the final two lines in your example with those above. Do you get any errors in Visual Studio or in your web browser console?

Comment: Opps! Sorry I recheck it again and the path I have given is wrong. Its working @Johnny Thanks :)